# NullPointerException : JUnit test for Repository

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa

Is it correct to write JUnit test case for Repository like this? Also while running it , Iam getting NullPointerException at line Mockito.when...
here is my test class:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:resources/invoices-context.xml",
        "classpath*:resources/invoices-int-schema.xml" })
public class RoomRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    RoomRepository roomRepository;

    private RoomEntity roomEntity;

    @Test
    public void findRommByDateTest() throws ParseException {
        String startDate = "27-07-2020";
        sDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").parse(startDate);
        String endDate = "28-07-2020";
        eDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").parse(endDate);
        String roomType = "SINGLE";

        roomEntity = new RoomEntity();
        roomEntity.setRoomId(1);
        roomEntity.setRoomPrice(6000);
        roomEntity.setRoomStatus("AVAILABLE");
        roomEntity.setRoomType("SINGLE");
        Mockito.when(
                roomRepository.findRoomByDate(Mockito.any(Date.class), Mockito.any(Date.class), Mockito.anyString()))
                .thenReturn(roomEntity.getRoomId());
        int id = roomRepository.findRoomByDate(Mockito.any(Date.class), Mockito.any(Date.class), Mockito.anyString());
        assertEquals(1, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: And why shouldn't it? There is no `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` so basically everything is ignored in your test hence a nullpointerexception.

Comment: Even after adding @RunWith(SpringRunner.class), I am still getting the exception

Comment: It cannot be `null` else your test simply would break with an error telling you that it couldn't be autowired. Also if you autowire the bean why use Mockito? If you want to mock why bother with an autowired field, then just mock it (which then will make your test useless as you aren't testing anything).

Comment: I am new to it , this is the first time I am writing JUnit for Repository. So, instead of using Mockito what alternate way can I use ?

Comment: Either write an integration test (with a database etc.) or don't write a test for the repository, mocking it and checking if the result is returned is only a test for the mocking framework not your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mocking the database fetch function, you can just use the embedded database setup with some annotations. It helps us to test the query efficiently. If you are using an in-memory database(embedded) first you have to add (save) entry in the table. Then your query function should fetch the data. With the help of this you can easily debug the null pointer exceptions.

Eg:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:resources/invoices-context.xml",
        "classpath*:resources/invoices-int-schema.xml" })
public class RoomRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    RoomRepository roomRepository;

    private RoomEntity roomEntity;

    @Test
    public void findRommByDateTest() throws ParseException {
        String startDate = "27-07-2020";
        sDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").parse(startDate);
        String endDate = "28-07-2020";
        eDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").parse(endDate);
        String roomType = "SINGLE";

        roomEntity = new RoomEntity();
        roomEntity.setRoomId(1);
        roomEntity.setRoomPrice(6000);
        roomEntity.setRoomStatus("AVAILABLE");
        roomEntity.setRoomType("SINGLE");

        //adding data for testing  
        roomRepository.save(roomEntity)
        
        //test the actual function
        int id = roomRepository.findRoomByDate(sDate,eDate);
        assertEquals(1, id);
   
}
```

Comment: I am doing it the way you suggested but I am getting IllegalStateException : Failed to load Application Context

Comment: This also happens if you have given incorrect query, can you paste the exact error message here

Comment: With me the problem is that , Repository Class and Main Class are in different modules. Say Repository is in module A within com.booking.model package. And Main Class is in module B within com.booking.service package.

Comment: I am new to all this , and unable to find out how to use i@SpringBootTest properly in this situation.